# Make changes to the fist line for each file in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 50 files which have a blank first line and column headers surrounded in double quotes on the second line. I want to delete the first line and remove double quotes " from the second line for every file.

Can both these changes be done in 1 regular expression or do I need to use two different expressions?

**Note**: I am unable to print the first line as blank in sample data as this website is not allowing me. The \n is just to denote an empty line.

Also the second line is different in all 50 file, so I cannot use simple find and replace. I need to use some regular expression.

Sample data.

```
\n
"PRODUCTID","ATTRIBUTENAME_VALUE","STATE"
"00300678116042","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
"00041260363603","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
```

Expected output

```
PRODUCTID,ATTRIBUTENAME_VALUE,STATE
"00300678116042","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
"00041260363603","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
```

Comment: Just out of interest...are the first lines in all the 50 files the same...?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work as one replace find in files:

Find what:  `^\r\n"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)"`

Replace with: `\1,\2,\3`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^\R)"([^"\n]*)
```

and replace it with `$1`.

pattern details:

```
(?:
    \G      # contiguous to the previous match
    (?!^)   # not at the start of the line
            # (to prevent \G to match the start of the string)
  |         # OR
    ^\R     # start of a line followed by a newline (an empty line)
)
"
([^"\n]*)   # capture group 1: all that is not a quote or a newline
            # (to reach the next quote)
```

Comment: Interesting, in my np++ 6.7.9.2 it didn't remove the first line but this worked: `(?<!.)^\R|\G"([^"\n]*)` and replace with `$1`. Instead of `(?<!.)^` I tried `\A` before which worked in regex101 but not alike in np++

Comment: @Jonny5: indeed np++ doesn't support the `\A` anchor and uses by default the multiline mode (so `^` matches always the start of the line). I missed that the empty line must be removed. I will correct that.